# Recuperar dados json ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

tenho essa requisição:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "teste.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function(data) {

                var nome = data["nome"];
                $("#dados_conteudo").empty();
                $("#dados_conteudo").append(data);
            }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });


    </script>
```

o retorno é algo do tipo:

```
{"data":{"cod":"123","nome":"Rafael"},"message":"OK","status":true}
```

quero pegar o cod e o nome e passar para variáveis php e trabalhar com elas... não estou conseguindo.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form" align="center">
<h3 align="center"><font color=#0005E0><strong>Teste</strong></font><br><br><font color=#B22222>
<td align="right">
    <font size="4" face="Arial" color=blue>
    <b>Login</b></font>

</td><br>
<td><input name="login" type="text" id="login" /></td></tr><tr> 
<td align="right">
    <font size="4" face="Arial" color=blue>

   <b>Senha</b></font>

</td><br>
<td><input name="senha" type="password" id="senha" /></td>
<br>    <label><input type="submit" class="but but-primary" name="enviar" value="Entrar" /></label>
</form>
```

Se o usuário existir, ou seja, for retornado cod e nome ele loga no sistema......

Comment: Podes mostrar a função/código que precisa de usar esses valores?

Comment: Quero passar os dados recebidos e verificar se estão cadastrados no sistema.. Me ajudando somente a colocar esses dados na tela separadamente já resolve.. o resto sei fazer... Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O `"nome"` esta dentro da chave `data` e a chave `data` esta dentro da variável de mesmo nome (`data`), você deve ter imaginado que a variável já representava a chave, então ao invés de

```
var nome = data["nome"];
```

Use:

```
data = data.data; //Sobrescreve o valor da var com o valor de "data":...
var nome = data["nome"];
var cod = data["cod"];
```

Ou

```
data = data.data;
var nome = data.nome;
var cod = data.cod;
```

Só pra constar, isto **não** funciona:

```
$("#dados_conteudo").empty();
$("#dados_conteudo").append(data);
```

`$(...).append` é uma função do jQuery para adicionar ou mover elementos HTML, não irá converter JSON para HTML.

---

**[editando]**

Se o `teste.php` é na verdade um serviço externo então o ideal seria fazer a autenticação via PHP mesmo e salvar os dados em uma sessão, por exemplo no lugar do teu `teste.php` (que suponho que venha de outro servidor) crie um arquivo chamado login.php:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['senha'])) {
    //Se falhar
    die(json_encode(array(
        'message': 'Faltam campos',
        'status': false
    )));
}

$url = 'https://www.site-externo.com/pagina-especifica/teste.php';

//Cria o POST para CURL
$postString = http_build_query($_POST, '', '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//Define um User-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

//retorna a resposta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Resposta
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data === false) {
    //Se falhar
    die(json_encode(array(
        'message': 'erro CURL ' . curl_error($ch),
        'status': false
    )));

} else {
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpcode < 200 || $httpcode >= 300) {
        //Se falhar
        die(json_encode(array(
            'message': 'erro HTTP ' . $httpcode,
            'status': false
        )));
    }
}

//Se tudo ocorrer bem decodifica a resposta do CURL
$resposta = json_decode($data, true);

if (empty($resposta['data'])) {
    //Se falhar
    die(json_encode(array(
        'message': 'Falha em decodificar o JSON',
        'status': false
    )));
} else if (!$resposta['status']) {
    //Se falhar no servidor externo informa o erro
    die(json_encode(array(
        'message': $resposta['message'],
        'status': false
    )));
}

session_start(); //Inicia a sessão

$_SESSION['dados'] = $resposta['data']; //Salva o cod e o nome na variavel

//informa que esta OK
die(json_encode(array(
    'message': 'OK',
    'status': true
)));
```

Agora no **site.php** adicione isto:

```
<?php
session_start();

...

?>

<!-- Isto é apenas um exemplo de como pegar os dados -->
<strong>Cod:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['dados']['nome']; ?>
<strong>Nome:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['dados']['cod']; ?>
```

Então no Ajax faça:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "login.php",
    data: dados,
    success: function(data) {
       if (data.status) {
           window.location = "site.php";
       } else {
           //Informa a mensagem de erro do login.php
           alert(data.message + ', status:' + data.status);
       }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('erro HTTP: ' + textStatus + ': ' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```